# How to prove this $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}a(n)\sin{[(\tau-n)x]}=0$

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series

when I study digital signal processing course  got this following math Problem (finite impulse response):the book give this reslut(But I can't see the proof on the book):

**Question:** Give the postive integer $N>2$, if for any real numbers $x$,we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}a(n)\sin{[(\tau-n)x]}=0$$
if and only if
$$\begin{cases}
\tau=\dfrac{N-1}{2}\\
a(n)=a(N-1-n),0\le n\le N-1
\end{cases}$$

Now I can prove **$\Longleftarrow $**

becasue if 
$$\tau=\dfrac{N-1}{2},~~~
a(n)=a(N-1-n)$$
then
$$\begin{align*}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}a(n)\sin{[(\tau-n)x]}&=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}a(n)\sin{[(\frac{N-1}{2}-n)x]}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N-1}{2}}a(n)\sin{[(\frac{N-1}{2}-n)x]}+\sum_{n=\frac{N+1}{2}}^{N-1}a(N-1-n)\sin{[(\frac{N-1}{2}-n)x]}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N-1}{2}}a(n)\sin{[(\frac{N-1}{2}-n)x]}-\sum_{n=0}^{\frac{N-1}{2}}a(n)\sin{[(\frac{N-1}{2}-n)x]}\\
&=0\end{align*}$$

**But How to prove $\Longrightarrow$**

This